# numpy.repeat MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble using the numpy.repeat fuction.  It is giving me a MemoryError.

```
    def __calculate_lon_data(self):
        lon_data = np.arange(self.min_lon, (self.max_lon + self.resolution),
                             self.resolution)
        lon_data = [unextend_lon(lon) for lon in lon_data]
        lon_data = np.float32(lon_data)
        lon_data = np.repeat(lon_data, self.y_dims)
        return lon_data
```

The resulting array is 18000 x 6501.

I'm successfully able to take the 6501 Latitude array and repeat it 18000 times, to fill out the full grid.  But when I try to take the 18000 Longitude array and repeat it 6501 times, that's when I get the MemoryError.

```
     File "scripts/rain_file.py", line 712, in __calculate_lon_data
    lon_data = np.repeat(lon_data, self.y_dims)
  File "miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 471, in repeat
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis=axis)
  File "miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 56, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
MemoryError
```

I've tried searching for this error, but I haven't yet found a solution.  TIA

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue.  My y_dims was getting changed without me realizing it to a much much larger number.  Now to fix that and I should be good.